# directory_iterator runs into segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++, c++17

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto iter = std::filesystem::directory_iterator("foo");
    for (auto &entry : iter) {
        std::cout << entry.path();
    }
}
```

When I run it and the directory `foo` exists, I get a SIGSEGV. So I started gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/krausefx/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555556a87 in std::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::~vector (
    this=0x23) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:567
567     std::_Destroy(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000555555556a87 in std::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::~vector (
    this=0x23) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:567
#1  0x00005555555566aa in std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::~path (this=0x3) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h:208
#2  0x0000555555557ebe in std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt::~_Cmpt (this=<incomplete type>) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h:643
#3  0x0000555555557ed9 in std::_Destroy<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> (__pointer=0x3) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:98
#4  0x0000555555557ced in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt*> (__first=0x3, __last=0x0)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:108
#5  0x00005555555576de in std::_Destroy<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt*> (__first=0x3, __last=0x0)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:137
#6  0x0000555555556fb9 in std::_Destroy<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt*, std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> (__first=0x3, __last=0x0)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:206
#7  0x0000555555556a9d in std::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::~vector (
    this=0x7fffffffdcf0) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:567
#8  0x00005555555566aa in std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::~path (this=0x7fffffffdcd0) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h:208
#9  0x000055555555630d in main (argc=32767, argv=0x7ffff7fadf40 <std::wcout>) at test.cpp:5
(gdb) p this
$1 = (vector * const) 0x23
```

So apparently, when initializing the `directory_iterator`, the destructor of `std::filesystem::path` gets called for some reason, and somewhere in there, the destuctor of `std::vector` is called on a `this` value of `0x23`, which obviously is a bad thing and leads to a SIGSEGV.

What's happening here? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a compiler bug (compiler is g++ 8.3.0)?

Comment: I would check whether the `directory_iterator` is valid before using it. Not directly relevant but `auto& entry` could be const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think std::filesystem is stable. It caused segfaults and other problems in my project (especially std::filesystem::path in mingw-w64 that ships with msys2). Try updating your gcc package and check if the problem persists. If it does then you can file a bug report or just wait and hope that someone already reported it (in my case updating fixed the problem).

Comment: My gcc is the newest Ubuntu provides. What version are you running?

Comment: @flyx 9.1.0, on Arch, but I also have msys2 and mingw-w64 at home on my windows machine, and there were problems with 8.x versions if I remember correctly. I don't know the current versions I have there though. I can check that later.

Also I think there is a package called gcc-9 on Ubuntu (but you might have to add a new repository to the list). EDIT: Just compiled and ran it with gcc 9.1 and it didn't crash

Comment: You were right. Ubuntu has a g++-9, it simply does not provide a `g++` alternative, but I can call it directly. That solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I checked `directory_iterator` works fine using GCC 8 under Ubuntu.

Be sure to add the linker flag `-lstdc++fs` when compiling.

If you don't compilation ends successful but, at least in my system, I get a segfault as you do when it starts iterating.